# GWT JSNI method exposure

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

I have a question regarding using JSNI to expose one of my GWT methods.

I have am trying to expose a method in one of my GWT classes that fires a message to other UI components.

In my application entry point I expose it with

```
   public native void exportMethods() /*-{
        $wnd.fireFoo=$entry(this.@myPackage.class_a::fireFoo(Ljava/lang/String;));
   }-*/;
```

class_a updates one of its fields, and then calls a static method from class_b.

```
   public class class_a{

       private String last_msg;

       public void fireFoo(String msg){
           this.last_msg = msg;
           class_b.foo(msg);
       }
   }
```

class_b calls many other classes and static methods to process the msg

```
   public class class_b{
       public static void foo(String msg){
       ...//creates a message object and sends it to UI components
       class_c.foo2(msg);
       ...
       }

   }
```

Basically, all I need to do is pass off a string and call a GWT method.  The method (when called from GWT and not handwritten JS) works perfectly.  I have also verified that the exposed method will fire a simple alert.  I believe the problem lies in calling the other classes' methods.

I get: "(TypeError) Unable to get property 'hv' of undefined or null reference description."

Is there a way to pass off a string to the original GWT method without having to go an expose the countless other methods that it will eventually run through?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like in JavaScript, `this.@myPackage.class_a::fireFoo(Ljava/lang/String;)` is a reference to a method, but it doesn't *bind* that method to the `this` object at that time. The `this` from inside the method will be determined at the time the function is called, **not** the time the reference is retrieved.

You thus need a *delegate*:

```
var that = this;
$wnd.fireFoo = $entry(function(s) {
  that.@myPackage.class_a::fireFoo(Ljava/lang/String;)(s);
});
```

If it indeed works in DevMode as you say, then it's a bug in DevMode.